# Disabling all Keys and Key-Combinations in JAVA

Tags: java, windows, focus, key

I want to disable the Windows-Key and all Windows-Key + X Combination while my Dialog is Visible. 
CTRL + SHIFT + ESC and ALT + TAB should be disabled too. 
Is this possible?
I Just want that my JDialog is always on Top, so not even the StartBar should be Visible.
Can someone help me with that out?

EDIT: Or a way to disable the keyboard.

Comment: Uhh.. that's not really a good idea. It's not user friendly. I think your application may be even considered a virus in some circumstances.

Comment: i hoped for a simplier solution to disable everything at once
the user should not be able to do anything, no, not a virus or something like that, the application will be connected to a server with several clients

Comment: Well what about the mouse? The user can switch focus with his mouse too.

Comment: my JDialog is in the size of the screen, so it hides everything where you can't click anywhere, it is only switchable with the keycombo that i want prevent

Comment: You can try JNA, see this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486167/is-it-is-possible-to-disable-the-windows-keys-using-java

Comment: oh.. looks interesting.. i will try.. feel free to answer other solutions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the [Robot Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) and have the robot constantly release all the keys you mentioned. As an example:

```
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

I believe that the user can still use CTRL+ALT+DEL to close the program.

Take a look at this question too: [Use Java to lock a screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744535/use-java-to-lock-a-screen)