# Netbeans project still running when using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe");`

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, runtime.exec

I'm working on a (non-malicious) screen-locking sort of Swing application, and I've adapted code from Martijn Courteaux's answer at [Use Java to lock a screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744535/use-java-to-lock-a-screen) to do this.  The problem is that when I use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe");` to reopen the Explorer process at program closing, Netbeans thinks that my project is still running because the resulting explorer.exe is running.  CMD prompt and JCreator don't have this issue.

Can anyone give an example of the preferred way to call a command like `explorer.exe` to avoid this happening with Netbeans?

**Edit:** I close the Explorer process at the start of the program (which includes the taskbar).  When I run Explorer, it's not to open a Windows Explorer window (which works totally fine with the given answers) but to restore the regular Windows UI.

Comment: The problem is `Runtime@exec` is waiting for the child process to exit.  This is actually quite common. There is trick to creating a childless process, but I don't have the code in front of me right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Runtime@exec` is waiting for the child process to exit.  This is the default behavior.

If you want to execute a parentless process (a process in which the parent process can terminate even though the child is still running), you need to get a little more creative.

We use...

```
"cmd /C start /B /NORMAL " + yourCommand
```

I would highlight recommend using `ProcessBuilder` as it makes it significantly easier to build and execute external commands.

Something like...

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "start", "/B", "/NORMAL", "explorer.exe");
pb.start();
```

For example....

*nb* I run this is NetBeans and the program exited after/as explorer opened.

There is one little draw back.  This doesn't like long file names.  You'll need to find some way to produce short file names/paths for this to work.  I was forced to use JNI solution for this

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth info and `ProcessBuilder` suggestion.  For now I think the `"cmd /C..."` will be fine for my purposes.

Comment: You're welcome.  Took me 2 weeks to figure all this out so happy to help others :P

Comment: As it turns out, this answer works for everything except for `explorer` (assuming Explorer isn't already running, in which case you'd just get a Windows/File Explorer window).  Good answer but it won't work for this exact case.  For now I'm using a Python script with `os.startfile("explorer")` to get this working.  Thank you again though.

Comment: Which explore where you hoping for?

Comment: I opened Windows Explorer and run the sample code a number of times, each time it opened a new Windows Explorer and exited.  I closed all the Window Explorer's and tried it again, each time, had the same result

Comment: Oh, I am pretty disappointed in myself right now... I didn't mention that I was closing Explorer (as in the taskbar, ALT+TAB, etc.) at the start of the program.  Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

ProcessBuilder allows you to create and control processes.

Here's some example code, it's fairly complex but I don't have time to dumb it down (no offense): https://github.com/Xabster/Botster/blob/master/src/commands/ExecCommand.java

Comment: But, it will not allow the JVM to exit, until the child process has terminated, back to the original problem the OP is having...

Comment: He can destroy it upon exit. Line 181.

Comment: But ;), as I understand it, the OP wants to launch the process and then have his program exit, WHILE the other process continues running. I agree, ProcessBuilder is a better solution to Runtime#exec though

Comment: That's not how I understood it. He can just run "cmd /K COMMAND_HERE" if that's the case.

Comment: Yes. Now add that your answer!